# How can you use an immutable Option by reference that contains a mutable reference?

Tags: reference, rust, immutability, mutability

Here's a `Thing`:

```
struct Thing(i32);

impl Thing {
    pub fn increment_self(&mut self) {
        self.0 += 1;
        println!("incremented: {}", self.0);
    }
}
```

And here's a function that tries to mutate a `Thing` and returns either true or false, depending on if a `Thing` is available:

```
fn try_increment(handle: Option<&mut Thing>) -> bool {
    if let Some(t) = handle {
        t.increment_self();
        true
    } else {
        println!("warning: increment failed");
        false
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of usage:

```
fn main() {
    try_increment(None);

    let mut thing = Thing(0);
    try_increment(Some(&mut thing));
    try_increment(Some(&mut thing));

    try_increment(None);
}
```

As written, above, [it works just fine (link to Rust playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a695198477ed5c8121362df22297d365). Output below:

```
warning: increment failed
incremented: 1
incremented: 2
warning: increment failed
```

The problem arises when I want to write a function that mutates the `Thing` twice. For example, the following does not work:

```
fn try_increment_twice(handle: Option<&mut Thing>) {
    try_increment(handle);
    try_increment(handle);
}

fn main() {
    try_increment_twice(None);

    let mut thing = Thing(0);
    try_increment_twice(Some(&mut thing));

    try_increment_twice(None);
}
```

The error makes perfect sense. The first call to `try_increment(handle)` gives ownership of `handle` away and so the second call is illegal. As is often the case, the Rust compiler yields a sensible error message:

```
   |
24 |     try_increment(handle);
   |                   ------ value moved here
25 |     try_increment(handle);
   |                   ^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
```

In an attempt to solve this, I thought it would make sense to pass `handle` by reference. It should be an *immutable* reference, mind, because I don't want `try_increment` to be able to change `handle` itself (assigning `None` to it, for example) only to be able to call mutations on its value.

My problem is that I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Here [is the closest working version that I could get](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2921c0146b834ad1ce1acc01dbb05392):

```
struct Thing(i32);

impl Thing {
    pub fn increment_self(&mut self) {
        self.0 += 1;
        println!("incremented: {}", self.0);
    }
}

fn try_increment(handle: &mut Option<&mut Thing>) -> bool {
    // PROBLEM: this line is allowed!
    // (*handle) = None;

    if let Some(ref mut t) = handle {
        t.increment_self();
        true
    } else {
        println!("warning: increment failed");
        false
    }
}

fn try_increment_twice(mut handle: Option<&mut Thing>) {
    try_increment(&mut handle);
    try_increment(&mut handle);
}

fn main() {
    try_increment_twice(None);

    let mut thing = Thing(0);
    try_increment_twice(Some(&mut thing));

    try_increment_twice(None);
}
```

This code runs, as expected, but the `Option` is now passed about by *mutable* reference and that is *not* what I want:

- I'm allowed to mutate the `Option` by reassigning `None` to it, breaking all following mutations. (Uncomment line 12 (`(*handle) = None;`) for example.)
- It's messy: There are a whole lot of extraneous `&mut`'s lying about.
- It's doubly messy: Heaven only knows why I must use `ref mut` in the `if let` statement while the convention is to use `&mut` everywhere else.
- It defeats the purpose of having the complicated borrow-checking and mutability checking rules in the compiler.

Is there any way to actually achieve what I want: passing an immutable `Option` around, by reference, and actually being able to use its contents?

Comment: "how can you use an immutable Option<>, by reference, that contains a mutable reference?" you can't as explain by the compiler "`t` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable"

Comment: @Stargateur - .Line 12 is `(*handle) = None;`

Comment: @Stargateur - I'm not mutating the option, though, because it contains a reference and I am not changing the reference. After my mutation, the reference is still pointing to the same thing. I am mutating something internal to that thing.

Comment: @Stargateur - Furthermore, using `RefCell` would not achieve the pattern that I want because I could change the `RefCell` to contain a different `Thing` entirely -- essentially the same as reassigning the `Option` to none. I could rewrite `Thing` to use `RefCell`, internally, but that would mean that I have to restructure my entire library and incur the cost of runtime-borrow-checking, everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: The answer is *No*, I can't.

After the discussions with @Peter Hall and @Stargateur, I have come to understand why I need to use `&mut Option<&mut Thing>` everywhere. `RefCell<>` would also be a feasible work-around but it is no neater and does not really achieve the pattern I was originally seeking to implement.

The problem is this: if one were allowed to mutate the object for which one has only an *immutable* reference to an `Option<&mut T>` one could use this power to break the borrowing rules entirely. Concretely, you could, essentially, have many ***mutable*** references to the same object because you could have many such immutable references.

I *knew* there was only one *mutable* reference to the `Thing` (owned by the `Option<>`) but, as soon as I started taking references to the `Option<>`, the compiler no longer knew that there weren't many of those.

The best version of the pattern is as follows:

```
fn try_increment(handle: &mut Option<&mut Thing>) -> bool {
    if let Some(ref mut t) = handle {
        t.increment_self();
        true
    }
    else {
        println!("warning: increment failed");
        false
    }
}

fn try_increment_twice(mut handle: Option<&mut Thing>) {
    try_increment(&mut handle);
    try_increment(&mut handle);
}

fn main() {
    try_increment_twice(None);

    let mut thing = Thing(0);
    try_increment_twice(Some(&mut thing));

    try_increment_twice(None);
}
```

Notes:

1. The `Option<>` holds the only extant mutable reference to the `Thing`
2. `try_increment_twice()` takes ownership of the `Option<>`
3. `try_increment()` *must* take the `Option<>` as `&mut` so that the compiler knows that it has the only mutable reference to the `Option<>`, during the call
4. If the compiler knows that `try_increment()` has the only mutable reference to the `Option<>` which holds the unique mutable reference to the `Thing`, the compiler knows that the borrow rules have not been violated.

#### Another Experiment

The problem of the mutability of `Option<>` remains because one can call `take()` et al. on a mutable `Option<>`, breaking everything following.

To implement the pattern that I wanted, I need something that is *like* an `Option<>` but, even if it is *mutable*, it cannot be mutated. Something like this:

```
struct Handle<'a> {
    value: Option<&'a mut Thing>,
}

impl<'a> Handle<'a> {
    fn new(value: &'a mut Thing) -> Self {
        Self {
            value: Some(value),
        }
    }

    fn empty() -> Self {
        Self {
            value: None,
        }
    }

    fn try_mutate<T, F: Fn(&mut Thing) -> T>(&mut self, mutation: F) -> Option<T> {
        if let Some(ref mut v) = self.value {
            Some(mutation(v))
        }
        else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I thought, I can pass around `&mut Handle`'s all day long and know that someone who has a `Handle` can only mutate its contents, not the handle itself. ([See Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a900b896d8932c22c6ac9e8bbb2116d0))

Unfortunately, even this gains nothing because, if you have a mutable reference, you can always reassign it with the dereferencing operator:

```
fn try_increment(handle: &mut Handle) -> bool {
    if let Some(_) = handle.try_mutate(|t| { t.increment_self() }) {
        // This breaks future calls:
        (*handle) = Handle::empty();

        true
    }
    else {
        println!("warning: increment failed");
        false
    }
}
```

Which is all fine and well.

Bottom line conclusion: just use `&mut Option<&mut T>`

Answer (score 3):

You can't extract a mutable reference from an immutable one, even a reference to its internals. That's kind of the point! Multiple aliases of immutable references are allowed so, if Rust allowed you to do that, you could have a situation where two pieces of code are able to mutate the same data at the same time.

Rust provides several escape hatches for [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html), for example the `RefCell`:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn try_increment(handle: &Option<RefCell<Thing>>) -> bool {
    if let Some(t) = handle {
        t.borrow_mut().increment_self();
        true
    } else {
        println!("warning: increment failed");
        false
    }
}

fn try_increment_twice(handle: Option<RefCell<Thing>>) {
    try_increment(&handle);
    try_increment(&handle);
}

fn main() {
    let mut thing = RefCell::new(Thing(0));
    try_increment_twice(Some(thing));
    try_increment_twice(None);
}
```

Comment: `RefCell` is there for deferring mutability checks to runtime. I want mutability checks at compile time and there should be no reason why that wouldn't be possible because I am not trying to mutate the `Option<>`. I am not event trying to change the options value because, after my mutations, the reference itself is not changed, only the interior state of the referenced object.

Comment: Furthermore, using RefCell would not achieve the pattern that I want because I could change the RefCell to contain a different Thing entirely -- essentially the same as reassigning the Option to none. I could rewrite Thing to use RefCell, internally, but that would mean that I have to restructure my entire library and incur the cost of runtime-borrow-checking, everywhere.

Comment: @Xharlie You could reassign the "different Thing entirely" through a `&mut` reference too.

Comment: In that case, I don't gain anything by using RefCell as opposed to using mutable `Option`'s.

Comment: @Xharlie Correct. Mutable Options might be better because they encode exactly what is going on and let the type-checker do it's thing. I suggested interior mutability only because you specifically asked for a solution with an immutable outer type.

Comment: I think you have helped me understand the problem. It is not a problem because my requirement doesn't make sense but rather because of the power that an immutable reference to an `Option<&mut T>` would provide. Specifically, because you can have many immutable references, this would essentially allow one to have many *mutable* reference, too, and completely break the mutability checking rules.

Comment: I still don't believe that `RefCell` is the answer, though. So, what I want is something like an `Option<T>` that, even when mutable, does not provide mutations on itself. `Option<T>` without `take()` et al.

For example, something like the `Handle` struct I hacked together in https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b4f73d38ee681f6a093ae2c6237fb7dc